# Angular http get with async await

Tags: angular, async-await

I have the following code in my service component, which gets me data from an api:

```
async getIngredientsByProductSubCategory(productSubCategoryId: number) {
    const url = '/my-url';
    let dataToReturn: any;
    await this.http.get(url).toPromise()
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            dataToReturn = data;
        });
    return dataToReturn;
}
```

The problem is that the console.log above outputs the correct data, but when i execute it from another component like this:

```
this.myService.getIngredientsByProductSubCategory(4);
```

i get this output from my console.log:

[image: log data of type "ZoneAwarePromise"]

What do i have to do, to get the correct data in the other component? Do i have to resolve this in any way?

**UPDATE:**

Working solution for me:

Service:

```
getIngredientsByProductSubCategory(productSubCategoryId: number) {
    const url = '/my-url';
    return this.http.get(url).toPromise();
}
```

Component:

```
async getIngredients() {
    const ingredientsByProductSubCategory = await this.frontendService.getIngredientsByProductSubCategory(4);
}
```

Also i read that if you don't have the requirement to consume recurring data, you may not use Observables.

Thanks to all for your help!

Comment: Why cant you just return Observable returned by http.get ??

Comment: You have to await `this.myService.getIngredientsByProductSubCategory(4)`

Comment: Don't use `then` with `await`. Just do `dataToReturn = await this.http...`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Does not change anything. Ive tried this before. I also read the article, but it didn´t help. I guess i'm missing something else here.

I know how to rewrite it to make it work. But i want to know why the data (which obviously is there) is not returned correctly.

Comment: Are you sure the console log you're seeing is the one you posted here and not from somewhere else?

Comment: @Jacob Yes, my logging is correct!

Comment: Then break each step down. Create a function that runs `return this.http.get(url);` Run that function, `getData`, and call it the normal Angular way, like `getData().subscribe(data => console.log(data))` see if the data is correct. If so, convert to promise and examine again, `var data = await getData().toPromise(); console.log(data);` see if the data is correct. Etc on up through the chain.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you, but i as i said is did this already! The data is not returned correctly when i call it from another component.

Comment: You have not shown the code where you are calling it from the other component. The code you have shown uses the incorrect method for getting data using `await`. You can insist all you want that you've done this already, but we can see no evidence of that in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are declaring getIngredientsByProductSubCategory as async, automatically this method will return a Promise, so, all `async`, `await` or `then` are redundant here. 
We can simply write:

```js
getIngredientsByProductSubCategory(productSubCategoryId: number) {
    const url = '/my-url';
    return this.http.get(url).toPromise();
}
```

and to consume that:

```js
const ingredientsByProductSubCategory = await getIngredientsByProductSubCategory(someId);
```

Comment: Thank you. That seems the correct way todo it. Also is have to declare the function in the other component as async when it is executed with await.

Answer (score 6):

**.toPromise()** is deprecated.

You should rather work with **firstValueFrom** or **lastValueFrom**.

Refer to this post for more details:
[Rxjs toPromise() deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67044352/18578004)

Comment: Could u please complete your answer with a working example?

Answer (score 1):

**.toPromise()** is deprecated. Here is how to use the new **lastValueFrom**

**Service**

```
  Login(phone:string,password:string)
  {
    let _headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'accept': 'application/json'
    });
    return this.http.post(this.url,{username,password},{headers:_headers})
                .pipe(map(response=>response));
  }
```

**Component**

```
  async Login(phone:string,password:string)
  {
    let token$ =  this.authService.Login(phone,password);
    let token = await lastValueFrom(token$);
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

You can return observable instead of data.
My solution is:

```
    getIngredientsByProductSubCategory(productSubCategoryId: number) {
      const url = '/my-url';
      return this.http.get(url);
}
```

To get data you need to subscribe to observable:

```
getIngredientsByProductSubCategory(4)
   .subscribe((data) => { dataToReturn = data; });
```

Comment: how is this relevant to async/await?